# Converting double to numeric - Sybase

Tags: sap-ase

I have a column with type double precision and I'd like copy values from this column to another column with type numeric(19,2).

When I do `select CONVERT( numeric(19,2), PriceNettoTmp) from Table` it works but when I do `update Table set PriceNetto = CONVERT( numeric(19,2), PriceNettoTmp)` it doesn't.

Error message for `update` when executing in Squirrel SQL:

> Data Truncation error occured on a write  of column -1Data was -1
>   bytes long and -1 bytes were transferred.

Error message for `update` when executing in Sybase Central:

> Could not execute statement. Arithmetic overflow during explicit
>   conversion of FLOAT NULL value '10,449999999999999.0' to a NUMERIC
>   field . Sybase error code=247 Severity Level=16, State=1, Transaction
>   State=0 Line 1

Anybody knows what can be wrong?

---

**EDIT**

I found a solution which works: `update Table set PriceNetto = CONVERT( numeric(19,2), str_replace(str(PriceNettoTmp,19,2),',','.'))`

Although I still don't understand why `select` was working and `update` not. And is there any simpler solution than my?

Answer (score 1):

Solution (as stated by OP)

```
update Table set PriceNetto = CONVERT( numeric(19,2), str_replace(str(PriceNettoTmp,19,2),',','.'))
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. I searched in [sybase book](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.blocks/html/blocks/blocks125.htm) about to convert string type number value to number but here also datatype list showing not have numeric datatype.

Now I got my answer here (NUMERIC datatype with scale and precision need to use) .